# Cakephp Conditions Between Times or if time column is not a time

Tags: mysql, datetime, cakephp

I have a table I need to pull records from if the row is between certain times.  But some of the times are UFN(until further notice).  How can I get cakephp to ignore the 'end' time if the end time is a string and not a time?  Would it be easier if I force the user to keep the 'end time' blank if they want to display UFN?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The project I'm working on is sensitive so I can't post any of the actual code, but here's an example.

```
$this->Event->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Event.active_start <' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date . " +31 minutes")),
        'Event.active_stop >' => $date,
        'Event.id >' => $id,
    ),
    'order' => 'Event.active_start',
    'group' => 'Event.id'
            )
        );
```

Event.active_start is always a datetime, but Event.active_stop can be a datetime or a string, usually 'UFN'.

This query is not pulling any rows that are strings.

Comment: It would help if you added sample data, expected results and any code you tried to this question.

Comment: I haven't tried any code because I don't know where to begin.  The can be easily achieved in php but I'd rather find a clean solution that will work in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make `'Event.active_stop'` as DATETIME field, allow to be empty.
2. Before save check if datetime format, if not unset($string)
3. After find (callback) if `active_stop` is empty field, return string 'UFN'